# Unsubscribe from Subject rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Can we unsubscribe from an Subject by calling `unsubscribe` on the Subject directly or you need to get the subscription first from the `subscribe`? If that is so, I'm just looking into understanding why you cannot call `unsubscribe` on the observable directly.

Comment: An Observable doesn't have the method unsubscribe.

Comment: Thank you I meant Subject rxjs. I fixed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you **can't have a subscription without subscribing to that observable first**.

Imagine there is an awesome newsletter, let's call it `X`. `X` produces content daily(this is when you're **building** the observable), but it sends the content weekly to **its subscribers**.
So only if you are a subscriber(you called `.subscribe()`), then you are going to **receive** the content and you can always **unsubscribe** from the newsletter.

On the other hand, if you are not a subscriber, you **can't receive** content, nor **unsubscribe** from the newsletter.

Comment: Does it still hold true for rxjs Subject? There is an unsubscribe method on it

Comment: I’d say so, even though a subject is a kind of observable, it is a little different. Referring to the above example, subscribers will receive content **after** you subscribe to X, so they won’t receive any previous values. If you want the previous value, you should have a look at BehaviorSubject. If you want all previous values, then ReplaySubject is your friend. Also, a Subject can act as an observable(emit values- the newsletter) or as an observer(receive values - the person interested in the newsletter content)

Comment: @AndreiGătej good example with the newsletter